# Adding the same event listener to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I saw similar questions but either they aren't close enough to what I want or are just as unclear as their respective answers -- let's see:

**What I have:** The following chunk of code:

```js
        addEventListener("load", function() {
            for(var x in document.getElementsByName("rbTipo")) {
                document.getElementsByName("rbTipo")[x].addEventListener("change", function() {
                    if(document.getElementById("rbTipoA").checked) {
                        document.getElementById("painelAluno").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementById("painelEscola").style.display = "none";
                    }
                    else if(document.getElementById("rbTipoE").checked) {
                        document.getElementById("painelAluno").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("painelEscola").style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("painelAluno").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("painelEscola").style.display = "none";
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**What it should do:**

- For each DOM element with `name="rbTipo"`, add it the `change` listener;
- Change CSS properties of third-party elements on their change.

**What it's doing wrong:**

Apparently `doc[...]byName("rbTipo")[x]` is not selecting the elements themselves. Means `x` is not the current iteration index of the array returned from `getElementsByName`?

**What I tried:**

Give each `name="rbTipo"` element their own listener. Doesn't seem logical since we're talking about doing something for multiple elements. Not a big deal since I have only two but I'll be doing this really really often, and not always with "just two" indexes.

Comment: Do a `console.log(x)` in the loop body. I think I've heard of browsers enumerability problems in `NodeLists`. You definitely should cache the collection in a variable, and use proper [array-like iteration over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Apparently Chrome enumerates NodeList from 1++, not 0++, which is really pointless to me. Make your comment an answer, please -- it's really useful.

Comment: Just as a head's up: While the answers below work, when you start getting into attaching a LOT of listeners, you will want to look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for(var x in document.getElementsByName("rbTipo"))
> ```

I wouldn't count on enumerability of `NodeList`s/`HTMLCollection`s. [Better use array-style iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Also, you shouldn't repeat the query, but store the collection in a variable. Btw, you *do* already give each element its own listener, which is a bit unnecessary.

```
addEventListener("load", function() {
    var rbTipos = document.getElementsByName("rbTipo"),
        rbTipoA = document.getElementById("rbTipoA"),
        rbTipoE = document.getElementById("rbTipoE"),
        painelA = document.getElementById("painelAluno"),
        painelE = document.getElementById("painelEscola");
    function listener() {
        if(rbTipoA.checked) {
            painelA.style.display = "block";
            painelE.style.display = "none";
        } else if(rbTipoE.checked) {
            painelA.style.display = "none";
            painelE.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            painelA.style.display = "none";
            painelE.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    for(var i=0; i<rbTipos.length; i++) {
        rbTipos[i].addEventListener("change", listener);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Find all the elements with `name="rbTipo"`, and loop through them, adding the listener to each:

```
var rbTipos = document.querySelectorAll('[name="rbTipo"]');
for (var i = 0; i < rbTipos.length; i++) {
  rbTipos[i].addEventListener('change', myEventFunction);
}
```